# Как сделать, чтобы для имён, начинающихся на «С», функция печатала строку Здравствуй, <имя>!, а для всех остальных — Привет, <имя>!

Tags: python

**В задание нужно использовать lambda - функцию**.
Измените код так, чтобы для имён, начинающихся на «С», функция печатала строку Здравствуй, <имя>!, а для всех остальных — Привет, <имя>!.
Программа должна напечатать такие строки:

Привет, Антон!
Здравствуй, Соня!
Привет, Коля!
Привет, Женя!
Привет, Тоня!
Здравствуй, Стёпа!

Вот сам код

```
people = ['Антон', 'Соня', 'Коля', 'Женя', 'Тоня', 'Стёпа']


def say_to_all(func, sequence):
    for item in sequence:
        func(item)


say_to_all(...)
```

Comment: В чем конкретная проблема? Не знаешь, как проверить первый символ?

Answer (score 1):

Делаем проверку, начинается ли имя на "С"

```
people = ['Антон', 'Соня', 'Коля', 'Женя', 'Тоня', 'Стёпа']

def say_to_all(func, sequence):
    for item in sequence:
        func(item)

say_to_all(lambda name: print(f"Здравствуй, {name}!") if name.startswith('С') else print(f"Привет, {name}!"), people)
```

Можем еще учесть, что имя будет начинаться с маленькой буквы:

```
people = ['Антон', 'Соня', 'Коля', 'Женя', 'Тоня', 'Стёпа', 'саша']

def say_to_all(func, sequence):
    for item in sequence:
        func(item)

say_to_all(lambda name: print(f"Здравствуй, {name}!") if name.lower().startswith('с') else print(f"Привет, {name}!"), people)
```

Comment: Если помог - поставь галочку, пожалуйста

Comment: Есть же встроенная функция `map`, зачем свой аналог писать? )  Лучше бы то, что в `lambda` функцией оформили, `lambda` не для длинных конструкций, они в ней плохо читаются.